# Issue with DB connection through JDBC

Tags: java, c3p0

```
 <!-- xml configs are follows -->
    <named-config name="MySQL">
        <property name="driverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcstudy</property>
        <property name="user">root</property>
        <property name="password">root</property>

        <property name="acquireIncrement">5</property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize">10</property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">5</property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">20</property>
    </named-config>
```

**DbUtilsUpdate.class**

```
package com.itheima.dbutils;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

public class DbUtilsUpdate {
    @Test
    public void update1(){
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
            //get date source
        ComboPooledDataSource source = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            conn = source.getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("update account set money=?where name=?");
            ps.setDouble(1, 999);
            ps.setString(2, "aaa");
            ps.executeQuery();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps, rs);
        }
    }
}

Database :
create table account(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(20),
    password double
)
```

error:

> Those are the whole error:
>       2015-4-1 15:18:22 com.mchange.v2.log.MLog 
>       信息: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
>       2015-4-1 15:18:22 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
>       信息: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
>       2015-4-1 15:18:22 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
>       信息: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3,
>   acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000,
>   autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null,
>   breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0,
>   connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName ->
>   wetmww98w558pm19wrp3o|1cfb549, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces ->
>   false, description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation
>   -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> wetmww98w558pm19wrp3o|1cfb549, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0,
>   initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0,
>   maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections
>   -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads ->
>   3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery ->
>   null, properties -> {}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin ->
>   false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout
>   -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
>       2015-4-1 15:18:51 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
>       警告: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@166a22b --
>   Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying
>   to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the
>   maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition
>   attempt exception: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:223)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:119)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
>         at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
>       2015-4-1 15:18:51 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
>       警告: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@47393f --
>   Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying
>   to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the
>   maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition
>   attempt exception: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:223)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:119)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
>         at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
>       2015-4-1 15:18:51 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
>       警告: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@120cc56 --
>   Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying
>   to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the
>   maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition
>   attempt exception: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
>         at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:223)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:119)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
>         at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

if i use the following codes ,the error will not appear,but i also don't know why.

```
ComboPooledDataSource source = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            source.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            source.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql:///jdbcstudy");
            source.setUser("root");
            source.setPassword("root");
```

Comment: Can you check the connection pool in your server to see if it being maxed out?

Comment: You should remove the `@Test` annotation from the `update1()` method as it is strictly an integration test because it involves the database.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ok,I'll make your advice in my mind ,bu i think the coed of ' DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps, rs);
' has the same meaning of 'conn.close()'

Comment: The error message doesn't match your question. it mentions the JDBC/ODBC bridge in the stack trace, yet your XML configuration uses a real JDBC driver.